# How does OutDir get determined during a WiX build?

Tags: tfs, wix

I've been having this strange issue for the last year or so.  In my wixproj file, I have an AfterBuild step that renames my msi based on the assembly version of a dll that gets created during the build, based on $(OutDir).  However, this variable seems to have random values.  Sometimes it's bin/x64/Debug.  Sometimes it's obj/Debug.  Sometimes it's just bin or obj.  It's also different on my local machine than on the TFS build server.  I've been having to put a flag to check whether I'm on the build server and arbitrarily change the source file location depending on where I'm building.  And sometimes it just randomly changes, the build breaks, and I have to go edit the wixproj file again by checking where it's looking.

What's going on here?

Comment: What version of TFS are you using? Are you using XAML build or the newer build system?

Comment: TFS 2017, and no we're not using xaml builds

Comment: Are you specifying a value for `OutDir` in the MSBuild arguments you're passing to the build step?

Comment: No, I'm not specifying it.  I'm just using whatever the default value MSBuild gives OutDir.  I guess that's my question...how is it determining this value?